# clarifying on properties in objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, properties

Sorry for the simple question.
When I see a definition of a property inside the `h file`, but **outside** of the class `@interface` scope, what does it mean ?

```
@property (nonatomic, readonly) RMMapContents *mapContents;
```

Here is the code:

```
@class RootViewController;
@class RMMapContents;

@interface MapTestbedAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {
    UIWindow *window;

    //MAIN VIEW
    //==============

    RootViewController *rootViewController;


    // NETWORK DATA
    // =============

    NSMutableArray  *photoTitles;         // Titles of images
    NSMutableArray  *photoSmallImageData; // Image data (thumbnail)
    NSMutableArray  *photoURLsLargeImage; // URL to larger image
    NSMutableData *receivedData;
    NSURLConnection *theConnection;
    NSURLRequest *request;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet RootViewController *rootViewController;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) RMMapContents *mapContents;


@end
```

Inside a function I see this line:

```
- (void)foo:(xyz *)abc{
  ..
  RMMapContents *mapContents = [self mapContents];
  ..
}
```

So, taking it from C++, the `mapContents` seem like it is not a global scope var (after all, that's why they call them properties, right?), but isn't defining the same name again inside the function weird a bit?

I hope someone can clarify a little here.
Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure that the `@property` is declared outside in the `@interface` section, because if I do that it will give a compile error.

Comment: What do you mean by out side of scope?? give your all definition of the interface in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The scope of the @interface block extends upto the @end keyword and is not restricted to the braces {}.

So the @property declaration lies very much inside the scope of the @interface and like cli_hlt rightly answered, it acts like a substitute to setter and getter methods for the mapContents property.

so a property named mapContents, would have setters and getters which look like this :

```
- (void)setMapContents; //setter

- (RMMapContents *)mapContents; //getter
```

and would can be accessed from within the class using these methods:

```
[self setMapContents:newContents];
```

AND

```
RMMapContents *contents = [self mapContents];
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, a property is not just a variable. A property is a variable plus its setter and getter methods. A property is usually said to be **backed** by a variable, which usually(but not always) has the same name as the property itself.

So there are basically three scenarios:

1. The developer has redefined the backing variable, look for something like:`@synthesize mapContents=mapContents_`, at the beginning of the implementation -> no problem here.
2. The compiler defined the variable to be something you don't now but not equal to    `mapContents` - > no problem.
3. The property backing variable is indeed called "`mapContents`", so then the local definition hides the global definition (look for a compiler warning here). But by calling `[self mapContents]` you will not access the global variable but call the getter, which in turn will access the class variable (because then the local `mapContents` is out of scope)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

global var mapContents is readonly,in foo function , create a new pointer,then you can change the value of inner var.

Answer (score 0):

Look for a method in your class with a name `mapContents` that will return a initialization to your `RMMapContents` class.

Basically this line    `RMMapContents *mapContents = [self mapContents];` says that initializing an instance of `RMMapContents` called `mapContens` using the method `mapContents`.